# Do trinkets have any effect in boss fights?

Tags: ys-origin

In Ys Origin, do the equipable trinkets (the ones that go in the fourth equip slot) have any effect in boss fights? I've noticed that, for example, the healing cape probably does not, or at least you can't afford to stand still for so long, but the revive trinket does work. But for example in Ys I the rings you can equip don't ever have any effect in boss fights.

For Yunica and Hugo, it wouldn't make much of difference, but the third character has the Cleria ring, which grants +3 attack and -3 defence. Are these bonuses in effect in boss fights or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YS Origin follows the same rules as YS I. Trinkets do not help in boss fights and they are only useful in the outside world. The Revive trinket works because it is an instant use.

Any trinkets that help attack/def will not work in boss fights. So for the Cleria Ring, you will not have a positive attack modifier and you will not have a negative modifier.

There is actually a video of a Boss fight that I like ([here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaeHnLwr6VE)).

Comment: That... is a really spectacular video.

Comment: @Humungus I know, Zero damage taken is so cool.